# Compensate tractor's (vehicle's) tilts in the GNSS-IMU based system

Tags: kalman-filter, imu, sensor-fusion, gps, filter

I have the following setup: a tractor with a dual band antenna (from ublox) installed on the vehicle's symmetry axis on the roof (h=3m), approx. 1m ahead of the center of the rear axis (which I consider to be a Pivot Point of the tractor). The antenna is connected to the C099-F9P board with the ublox ZED-F9P high precision module. Moreover, I have the RTK correction data which I feed to ZED-F9P, therefore the position is rather accurate (around 2cm accuracy).

Near the antenna, I have mounted a BNO08X IMU sensor, which is set to produce the so-called 'game rotation vector' (Euler angles: yaw, pitch, roll).

I use this sensor for two purposes:

1. To precisely calculate vehicles heading (ZED-F9P gives a steady in time, but rough estimates of heading, whereas BNO08X produces highly accurate heading for a certain moment, but it drifts over time). I use them in a form of a sensor fusion, which can be depicted as follows:

```
    IMU_angle ---------+----------+-------------------------------------------> fusion output
                       |          |                                                ^ -
                       |          |                                                |
                       |          +---> process noise ------> kalman filter -------+
                       |+                                         ^
                -      v                                          |
    GPS_angle ---> heading diff ------> measurement noise --------+
```

2. To compensate any tilts while driving on a bumpy fields. In this case the antenna can move about +/- 15cm side to side, even when the tractor drives on a straight line in terms of navigation and map projection. This produces a problem for my application because it sees the antenna moving side to side and it 'thinks' my vehicle does a small amplitude 'sinusoidal' movements.

I've tried to address the 2nd problem in the following manner:

- sample position, on average, with T_pos = 100ms (10Hz),
- sample BNO08X, on average, with T_imu = 50ms (20Hz),
  Since I know 'antenna vector' (vector from the physical vehicle's Pivot Point to the antenna) I can compute the true pivot point by:
- rotating the antenna vector by IMU's temporary roll, pitch and yaw,
- substracting from the obtained XYZ position (from the antenna) the rotated vector's components (x_antenna - x_rotated = x_true, ...)

I then pass the obtained values (x_true, y_true, z_true) to a simple 'moving average' filter in order to get rid of unwanted noise.

The problem is that even though I know I drive the vehicle on a straight line, after the compensations the XY plot shows the non-straight, sinusoidal movement. What am I doing wrong? Should I try different approach?

I have a feeling that maybe I should use some Kalman fusion algorithm (or Extended Kalman Filter?) to somehow  auto-magically compensate GPS antenna tilts with Euler angles coming form IMU - but I cannot find any whitepaper for inspiration how to implement it.

My goal is to have a situation where, despite tractor's cabin tilts aside during a forward movement, I receive straight movement trajectory

Comment: Do a web search for "open-source GNSS IMU fusion".  You should find much better solutions than trying to take a couple of incomplete solutions and hacking them together.